# One activity using with two adapter in android

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

Im using RecyclerView and ExpandableListView in an Activity, both load data to one layout, I have tried to use this activity call to one Adapter but it seem unsuccess.

This is my Activity (use two adapters):

```
public class DetailListCarActivityDemo extends AppCompatActivity {
  private RecyclerView mRecyclerView, exRecyclerView;
  private GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
  private RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
  private ExpandableListAdapter exAdapter;
  private Context context;

private ArrayList<GetterSetter> feedItemList;
// private List<Item> itemsListData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_list_car_demo);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
    collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Honda CRV Test");

    //find recyclerview layout
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    exRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    exRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    // recyclerview set layoutmanager
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,3);
    mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return (3 - position % 3);
        }
    });
    // RecyclerView.LayoutManager lm = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    //adding data to arraylist
    feedItemList = new ArrayList<GetterSetter>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        GetterSetter getterSetter = new GetterSetter();
        feedItemList.add(getterSetter);
    }

    //recyclerview adapter
    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(DetailListCarActivityDemo.this, feedItemList);
    //set adpater for recyclerview


    List<ExpandableListAdapter.Item> data = new ArrayList<>();

    data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.HEADER, "Fruits"));
    data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Apple"));
    data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Orange"));
    data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Banana"));
    data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.HEADER, "Cars"));
    data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Audi"));
    data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Aston Martin"));
    data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "BMW"));
    data.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Cadillac"));

    ExpandableListAdapter.Item places = new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.HEADER, "Places");
    places.invisibleChildren = new ArrayList<>();
    places.invisibleChildren.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Kerala"));
    places.invisibleChildren.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Tamil Nadu"));
    places.invisibleChildren.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Karnataka"));
    places.invisibleChildren.add(new ExpandableListAdapter.Item(ExpandableListAdapter.CHILD, "Maharashtra"));

    data.add(places);

    exRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(data));

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  }
 }
```

My layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!--
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cardList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
-->

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/mercedes"
            android:contentDescription="@string/paralax"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

I want to ask can I devide by two adapter and load data to one layout ?

Comment: yes you can..you can use multiple adapter in one layout.. please show your code, so we can help you solve your problem.

Comment: @MuhammadHafiqlqmal: thanks for reply, I have post my activity, it seem only an adapter called, other adapter is not call

Comment: if you need more anything, i will post more..

Comment: it just replace the adapters. you should use seperated recyclerview for each adapter

Comment: oh.. you mean one view.. one view can use different adapter but can't use different adapter in the same time. What you did is you use it in the same time. Just create 2 recyclerview to use them..

Comment: @luongkhanh please add your xml file

Comment: Yes, I want to load data same time in layout, one adapter is load in cardview and one adapter load in expandable

Comment: @masoud vali: I have posted activity_detail_list_car_demo.xml file

Comment: you are using the same recyclerview twice. you have to use two seperated recyclerviews in your xml file

Comment: thanks for your detected, how to seperated recyclerviews in xml, can you answer me? and then I can vote